# Swift: passing params - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire and passing my parameters to a function I made.

Here's my code:

```
let msisdn : AnyObject = textFields[0].text!
//let msisdn = textFields[0].text!
let userId = "MyID"

let params = [
    "msisidn":msisdn /*as AnyObject*/,
    "denom_id":self.selectedGameDetail.Id /*as AnyObject*/,
    "game_id":self.selectedGameDetail.GameId /*as AnyObject*/
]

print(params)
showEZLoading(true)
su.postEpins(userId, params: params, completion:{ (result, error) -> Void in
    self.hideEZLoading()
    if (error != nil){
        print("DEBUG: API Response Error")
        Utility.displayAlert(self, msg: "There's an errror fetching data from server.")
    }
    else {
        print("DEBUG: API Response Success")
    }
})
```

***Everything in `selectedGameDetail` is a String.***

And here's the `postEpins` function:

```
func postEpins(msisdn: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?, completion:(result: JSON, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    print("POST EPINS")
}
```

Doesn't do anything yet. But, whenever the app gets to the function call, I get this:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm positive it has something to do with the `params`, but I'm 100% sure. Yes, `params` has stuff in it. Check below.

**What I've tried:**

Well, if you see a comment in my code, I've pretty much tried those. And I have no idea what else to do.

For reference, that exact same code works on another part of the app, minus the `userID` - and I also tried removing that, but it still gave me the above error.

I found this regarding the `params`:

[image]

I noticed that one of the values is an NSTaggedPointerString, whereas everything else is an AnyObject. Is this an issue?

Comment: Most likely the value of `denom_id` is `nil`

Comment: @vadian, strange, but I can print out `params`: `["denom_id": 1, "game_id": G00000000205, "msisidn": 639000946500]`

Comment: maybe try `"denom_id":String(self.selectedGameDetail.Id)` ? unless you want it to be an Int, then do `Int(self.selectedGameDetail.Id)`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it really gets past the print call before crashing?


In any event, try literally setting all the values in the params dictionary to explicit string constants and see what happens. If that works you know the problem is in the setup; otherwise, it's related to the function.